# CSS subsequent transitions with graphic/codepen

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate two images to a center point and then rotate them concurrently. I'm not sure how to transform the svgs before the animation begins. See the following model.

[image]

I need to do a `transform: rotate(90deg)` before the animation begins (on `:hover`). I can't seem to get the `transform` to take effect before the animation. See the following codepen:

See my codepen: http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/dPzVmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of delaying the animation

```
.svg-container-burger {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwise 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

and trying to rotate the objects before the animation, just extend the animation to the pause prior to it, and set the rotation in it

```
.svg-container-mouth {
    -webkit-animation: rotateClockwise 2s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwise {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEJwya)

Comment: Smart solution. Thanks for the help.